# Angular conditional date pipe

Tags: json, angular, api, angular-pipe, angular-date-format

I want to format `createdDate` using date pipe which is coming from an `api`, and render in my `html` template how can this be done?

The `api` response looks like:

Json:

```json
    {
        "id":18, 
        "firstName":"Zeeshi", 
        "lastName":"Mughal", 
        "userName":"zeeshi", 
        "email":"zeeshan.ahmad@codeteck.com", 
        "emailVerified":0, 
        "phone":"+92307886689", 
        "phoneVerified":0, 
        "role":"Employee",
        "createdDate":"2021-11-30T06:12:51.000Z"
    }
```

Html:

```html
    <div class="first-name" 
        *ngFor="let profileinfo of profileinfo | keyvalue">
        <h2>
            <span class="info-color">{{profileinfo.key}}</span>
        </h2>
        <p>
            {{ profileinfo.value}}
        </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: You might want to add some more business logic to your post, especially regarding `profileinfo`. That aside, simply using the `date` pipe should do the trick, ie `{{ yourObject.createdDate | date }}`.

Comment: {{object.createdDate | date : 'shortDate '}}